# filename contains space and wildcard in a variable

Tags: file, bash, wildcard, space

I receive files which names contain spaces and change every week (the name contains the week number)

IE, the file for this week looks like `This is the file - w37.csv`

I have to write a script to take this file into account.
I didn't succeed in writing this script.

If I do :

```
    $FILE="This is the file - w*.csv"
```

I don't find `/dir/${FILE}`

I tried `"This\ is\ the\ file - w*.csv"`

I tried `/dir/"${FILE}"` and `"/dir/${FILE}"`

But I still can't find my file

It looks like the space in the name **needs** the variable to be double-quoted but, then, the wildcard is not analysed.

Do you have an idea (or THE answer)?

Regards,

Olivier

Answer (score 5):

```
echo /dir/"This is the file - w"*.csv
```

or — you almost tried that —

```
echo /dir/This\ is\ the\ file\ -\ w*.csv
```

Comment: Thanks but my problem is to use the name in a variable in a script

Comment: How do you want it in a single variable? And what for? You can either have the pattern in the variable and then expand it as needed or you can have it with some custom separator, or you may want to have an array. What are you going to do with this variable?

Answer (score 3):

Use a bash array

```
v=( /dir/This\ is\ the\ file - w*.csv )
```

If there is guaranteed to be only one matching file, you can just expand `$v`. Otherwise, you can get the full list of matching files by expanding as

```
"${v[@]}"
```

or individual matches using

```
"${v[0]", "${v[1]}", etc
```

Comment: Wow, this solved my problem. Thanks.
I receive only one file per week, so the file should be uniq but I prefer to make as if I may receive more than one.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should not use the dollar sign in an assignment.

Moreover, wildcard expansion is not called in an assignment. You can use process substitution for example, though:

```
FILE=$(echo 'This is the file - w'*.csv)
```

Note that the wildcard itself is not included in the quotes. Quotes prevent wildcard expansion.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't solve my problem. Still the system try to find "/dir/This", then "is", then "the", then "file", etc.
If I set "/dir/${FILE}" then, back to the beggining, the wildcard is not expanded

Comment: @OlivierGérault: Double quote the variable when used: `ls /dir/"$FILE"`

Comment: ls /dir/"$FILE" -> No such file or directory. Of course, the file exists

Comment: @OlivierGérault: Works for me: `touch 'a b c 23.csv' ; FILE=$(echo 'a b c '*.csv) ; ls ./"$FILE"`