# Bash: Copy files between directories that have spaces in their names and which are held in a variable

Tags: bash, cp

I'm using bash to copy files from one directory to another.

This works fine:

```
mkdir "test dir"
mkdir "test dir 2"
touch "test dir/fileone"
touch "test dir/filetwo"
cp -r "test dir/"* "test dir 2/"
```

But when trying to assign the dirs to variables in a script it doesn't work:

```
// Setup
mkdir "test dir"
mkdir "test dir 2"
touch "test dir/fileone"
touch "test dir/filetwo"
from="test dir"
to="test dir 2"
```

```
cp -r "$from"* "$to"
// FAIL: cp: cannot copy a directory, 'test dir 2', into itself, 'test dir 2/test dir 2'
// This seems to be equivalent of cp -r ./* "$to"
```

```
cp -r "$from*" "$to"
// FAIL: cp: cannot stat 'test dir*': No such file or directory
// This is treating * as a string rather than a wildcard
```

I found this existing answer but I couldn't get it to work and the answers didn't add much detail so I didn't really understand how it was meant to work: [filename contains space and wildcard in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12456562/filename-contains-space-and-wildcard-in-a-variable)

```
v=( ./test\ dir/ *)
echo "${v[@]}"
./test dir/ test dir test dir 2
// This seems to create an array of the string "test dir" and the contents of my current directory namely "test dir" and "test dir 2"
```

Comment: The problem is that the wildcard `"test dir"*` matches `"test dir 2"`

Comment: Why are you using a wildcard? Are there multiple `test dir` directories that should be used as the source?

Comment: can you use a different naming scheme for your source and destination directories, so that they don't match the same pattern?

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with the spaces. It's just because the wildcard matches both directories.

Comment: You would have the same problem if they were named `testdir` and `testdir2`

Comment: You're missing the directory separator: `"$from"*` should be `"$from"/*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's just one source directory, don't use a wildcard.

```
from="test dir"
to="test dir 2"
cp -r "$from" "$to"
```

Comment: This results in `test dir/test dir 2/fileone` rather than `test dir/fileone`. The wildcard copies the contents of the directory rather than the directory itself EDIT: Actually sorry no it doesn't. I think i've made a typo.

Comment: Sorry my mistake I don't know why I thought I needed a wildcard to copy the contents

Comment: The problem was that you were missing a `/` before the wildcard.